# Error: "El termino "nombre de variable" no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable"

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me aparece este error cuando nombro cualquier variable, no importa el nombre que le ponga simplemente sale ese error.

Como se ve en la captura uso PowerShell.

Comment: Ese es un error de PowerShell, y ocurre porque no estás ejecutando la instrucción dentro de python. Intenta lanzarlo escribiendo `python` +enter o `python3`+enter para entrar a python.